# ArrayList in andrid does not return data while fetching data from firebase database

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist, android-databinding

I am trying to get records from firebase database and return all the record within a array list but inside the for loop it will add records but when we check outside the loop it does not contain records. can anyone please help me i am new in android.Here is the code for fetching data..

```
public class DataBaseManagement {
public static ArrayList<Property> getAllProperties(Context context, DatabaseReference dbProperty){
    
    ArrayList<Property> propertyList = new ArrayList<Property>();

    dbProperty.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DataSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                Property tempProp;
                for (DataSnapshot aProp: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    tempProp = aProp.getValue(Property.class);
                    propertyList.add(tempProp);
                }
                Toast.makeText(context, "Total Properties : " + propertyList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // Here it will show the number of records
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "No record found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    Toast.makeText(context, "Total Properties : " + propertyList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // here it will not show the number of records
    return propertyList;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

as I know in addOnSucessListener it works in background thread
the fun will return and finish the background thread I think if you want it change return fun to void and use out fun liveData and update it inside addOnSucessListener